# AWK - how to improve this example

Tags: awk

Contents of the directory:

```
$ ls | awk '1'
ala
cztery.AVI
dwa.AvI
Jeden.aVI
lupa.com
PIĘĆ.AVI
trzy.Avi
zero.avi
```

This command prints:

```
$ ls | awk '$0=tolower($0){a=substr($0,1,length($0)-4)}{if(/avi$/){system("echo "$0" "a"\".mpg\"")}}'
cztery.avi cztery.mpg
dwa.avi dwa.mpg
jeden.avi jeden.mpg
pięć.avi pięć.mpg
trzy.avi trzy.mpg
zero.avi zero.mpg
```

How to improve the above command? I want to print:

```
cztery.avi cztery.mpg
dwa.avi dwa.mpg
jeden.avi Jeden.mpg
pięć.avi PIĘĆ.mpg
trzy.avi trzy.mpg
zero.avi zero.mpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls | awk '{lc=tolower($0)} lc~/\.avi$/{sub(/...$/,"mpg"); print lc,$0}'
```

Note that this won't work for file names that contain newlines. If you have that situation let us know.

You said in your comments below:

> I want the system to run this command ->
>
> ```
> ls | awk '{a=substr($0,1,length($0)-4)}/avi$|AVI$/{system("ffmpeg -i "$0" -f avi -vcodec libxvid "a"\".mpg\"")}'
> ```

As I mentioned, that's just not thinking the right way about it. To make it explicit, you are doing this:

```
shell ( ls | awk ( system( shell ( ffmpeg ) ) ) )
```

Wouldn't this make more sense:

```
shell ( ls | awk; ffmpeg )
```

I actually don't understand why you're using awk at all for this since it's trivially done all in shell, but assuming you have your reasons, here's the right way to implement what you posted:

```
ls *.avi *.AVI |
awk '{print $0, substr($0,1,length($0)-3) "\"mpg\""}' |
while read -r orig mpeg
do
    ffmpeg -i "$orig" -f avi -vcodec libxvid "$mpeg"
done
```

Note that that will fail if you have spaces in your file names but it's pointless fixing that when this is the better solution anyway:

```
ls *.avi *.AVI |
while IFS= read -r orig
do
    ffmpeg -i "$orig" -f avi -vcodec libxvid "${orig%avi}mpeg"
done
```

Note that your initial requirement of translating file names to lower case vanished in the solution you said you wanted to implement.

Also, note that this solution, since it's based on what you said you anted to implement, will not work for your originally posted list of files since it only works for files that end in .avi or .AVI, not .Avi. `ls *.[Aa][Vv][Ii]` would fix that if necessary.

Comment: Please awk solution, which uses the system (). Since the system will be used to start another bash command.

Comment: No. You need to stop trying to use system() at every opportunity as it is almost always the wrong approach. If you update your question to tell us what you're trying to do we can provide the right solution and it almost certainly will NOT involve calling system().

Comment: I want the system to run this command -> `ls | awk '{a=substr($0,1,length($0)-4)}/avi$|AVI$/{system("ffmpeg -i "$0" -f avi -vcodec libxvid "a"\".mpg\"")}'`

Comment: No, you don't. You want to write a script to accomplish some goal. You THINK that using system() is the right way to implement that script. It is not. I'll updated my answer with the right way to do it, assuming there's nothing else you haven't told us yet.

Comment: @EdMorton, Thank you for the explanation and presentation of a better solution.

Comment: You're welcome. When posting questions just try to focus on WHAT you're trying to do, not HOW you think you should do it as that can drive all of the answers you get in the wrong direction. It is good to post what you've tried, of course, just make sure that's clearly secondary to the purpose of your posting.

Answer (score 3):

How about using find first to match all the `avi` files:

```
$ find -iname "*.avi" -exec basename {} \; | awk -F. '{print tolower($1) ".avi", $1 ".mpg"}'
cztery.avi cztery.mpg
dwa.avi dwa.mpg
jeden.avi Jeden.mpg
pięć.avi PIĘĆ.mpg
trzy.avi trzy.mpg
zero.avi zero.mpg

$ ls -1 # Use the -1 option of ls instead of ls | awk '1'
ala
cztery.AVI
dwa.AvI
Jeden.aVI
lupa.com
PIĘĆ.AVI
trzy.Avi
zero.avi
```

If you're looking for the shortest solution use [Guru](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13801870/awk-how-to-improve-this-example/13802783#13802783)'s `ls` with my `awk`:

```
ls *.[aA][vV][iI] | awk -F. '{print tolower($1)".avi",$1".mpg"}'
cztery.avi cztery.mpg
dwa.avi dwa.mpg
jeden.avi Jeden.mpg
pięć.avi PIĘĆ.mpg
trzy.avi trzy.mpg
zero.avi zero.mpg
```

Comment: Thank you for a good solution. If possible, please correct my example.

Comment: What would happen if the filename contained more than one literal `.` ?

Comment: @steve is this a bonus round :P `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."}{$NF=""; NF--; print tolower($0),"avi "$0,"mpg"}'`

Comment: @steve is right, though, multiple "."s in a file name is a very common occurrence. Also, the posted `ls` command would fail if you have a file named "peccavi" in your directory as it's missing a ".".

Comment: Please awk solution, which uses the system (). Since the system will be used to start another bash command.

Comment: @EdMorton @ steve common occurrence, not in this case however, wasn't in the spec, OP never said this was an example case.

Comment: @sudo_O I don't think it's safe to assume the files the OP posted are explicitly THE only files he'll ever want to run his command on. If so there's a much briefer solution ;-)!

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
ls  *[aA][vV][iI] | awk '{print tolower($0) " " substr($0,0,length($0)-3)"mpg";}'
```

Comment: The filename in the 2nd column should retain the original case.

Comment: `" "` could simply become `,`. `awk`'s default OFS is a single space.

Comment: The posted ls command would fail if you have a file named "peccavi" in your directory as it's missing a "."

Comment: Please awk solution, which uses the system (). Since the system will be used to start another bash command.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it using `GNU awk`:

```
for i in *.[Aa][Vv][Ii]; do echo "$(echo $i | awk '{ print tolower($0), gensub(/...$/,"mpg","") }')"; done
```

Results:

```
cztery.avi cztery.mpg
dwa.avi dwa.mpg
jeden.avi Jeden.mpg
pięć.avi PIĘĆ.mpg
trzy.avi trzy.mpg
zero.avi zero.mpg
```

Comment: That would fail if $i contains globbing characters, etc. Always quote your variables. Also not sure what the point of the wrapping echo is and there's no point forcing it to be gawk-sepcific with gensub() in this case.

Comment: Please awk solution, which uses the system (). Since the system will be used to start another bash command.